# How to download images in playframework jobs?

Tags: java, asynchronous, concurrency, playframework, download

I have a playframework Job class like this:

```
public class ImageDownloader extends Job {
 private String[] urls;
 private String dir;

 public ImageDownloader(){}
 public ImageDownloader(String[] urls,String dir){
   this.urls = urls;
   this.dir = dir;
 }

 @Override
 public void doJob() throws Exception {
   if(urls!=null && urls.length > 0){
     for (int i = 0; i < urls.length; i++) {
       String url = urls[i];
       //Dowloading
     }
   }
 }
}
```

Play(1.2.4) has lots of amazing tools to make things easy.

So i wonder whether there's a way to make the downloading easy and beautiful in play ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a [built-in HTTP client in Play](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.4/libs#WebServiceclient).

With it, you can do HTTP requests like this:

```
HttpResponse res = WS.url("http://www.stackoverflow.com").get();
```

You can then get the content of the response in, for example, stream format:

```
InputStream is = res.getStream();
```